# Is it OK to put javascript/jquery code in multiple-level curly braces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-regions

My intention is to create C#-like `custom code region` for my jquery/js scripts.

I just don't know if it is OK or may create any un-awareness bug later on?

E.g.

```
{ //region Some Region Description
  console.log('Some js code');

  { //region Inner Region Description
    $('someSelector').html('Some elements');
  } //endregion

} //endregion
```

Comment: I don't think this is how you want to do it. Assuming you are using VS try creating a region `By marking a section of code (regardless of any logical blocks) and hitting CTRL + M + H `

Comment: I'm not coding with VS. Thanks any way.

Comment: In that case, what are you trying to accomplish? Is it just code folding? If so, what editor are you using?

Comment: Just the code folding ís the goal for javascript. I often use Notepad++, PyCharm, Netbeans, etc. VS is long ago and not for now.

Comment: Normally I would set them in the editor like my first comment, but if you're using multiple editors I might actually do it like your example. As long as you/your developers don't use `let` without knowing how it works you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are creating are statement blocks. Prior to ES6 I can't think of any side effects of doing that, but using intrinsic language features for semantics like that is pretty ugly.

ES6 introduces block scoped syntax e.g. [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Scoping_rules_2) and [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) statements so what you suggest could make things confusing.

Comment: May you give me the official URL to read on let/const of ES6? Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Scoping_rules_2

Comment: How to tell the article is ES6 not other older version @AlexK?

Comment: And after I read it, I see with inner scopes, I agree creating scopes will effect variables defined by `let` or `const`

Answer (score 1):

In ES5 Javascript one would tend to scope a block of code using an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

e.g.

```
(function () { //region Some Region Description
  console.log('Some js code');
  (function () { //region Inner Region Description
     $('someSelector').html('Some elements');
  }()); //endregion
}()); //endregion
```

IIFE's provide all of the benefit of scoped blocks, but definitely at the expense of readability.

Comment: Nice to know this; though too much agree with you on low readability.